# Amazone aws KVS Video streaming using Access key ID Secret access key in Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-support-library

I am using Amazon KVS Video Streaming Service. I need help in below 2 points.

1. I know that vedio streaming can be done in 2 ways. First using web RTC and second using KVS video Streaming. I want to know how can it be done using KVS video Streaming? I have Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.
2. I want to achieve this without creating cognito user.
3. Is it possible to make this happen without pool ID ?

I am following below reference.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producersdk-android-downloadcode.html
- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to the [KinesisVideoAndroidClientFactory](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/main/aws-android-sdk-kinesisvideo/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/kinesisvideo/client/KinesisVideoAndroidClientFactory.java#L71-L79) is a generic [`AWSCredentialsProvider`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/main/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.java#L18-L24).

The [`AWSMobileClient`](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/how-it-works/q/platform/android), which provides authentication via Cognito, is one example of an `AWSCredentialsProvider`.

However, there are other implementations of the `AWSCredentialsProvider`. One of the simplest possible solutions is to use a [`StaticCredentialsProvider`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/8018b729f6508944507eab9a097a50615c4576ba/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/internal/StaticCredentialsProvider.java#L21-L25), to provide some [`BasicAWSCredentials`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/main/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/BasicAWSCredentials.java#L18-L26).

In Kotlin:

```kotlin
val credentials =
    BasicAWSCredentials(your, secretKey)
val provider =
    StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)
val kinesis =
    KinesisVideoAndroidClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(applicationContext, provider)
```

Or Java:

```java
AWSCredentials credentials =
    new BasicAWSCredentials(your, secretKey);
AWSCredentialsProvider provider =
    new StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
KinesisVideoClient kinesis =
    KinesisVideoAndroidClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(getApplicationContext(), provider);
```

---

That's how you'd do it. Now, should you? Sure, for debugging and development. But, this solution requires you to bake AWS access credentials into your code. The solution is of a low security posture and I do not recommend it for production use. Please review [Best practices for managing AWS access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html), and consider using `AWSMobileClient` / Cognito, instead.